# How can I connect SV checker to vr_ad

Tags: specman

I am to integrate a checker implemented in SystemVerilog, to a mostly e verification environment. How can this SV checker connect to my vr_ad? Or should I implement the registers model also in SV?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement vr_ad in SV. You can stil implement it in e code and connect it to SV through vr_ad sequences. This feature is new to version 14.1.

Answer (score 0):

No need to rewrite register model. Starting version 14.1 one can access vr_ad objects and fields directly from SV.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 14.1 version, you can connect vr_ad to sv code as well.